# php variable in MySQL row name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with structure

```
TableName | Row1 | Row2 | Row3 ...etc
```

My 'Row' table column goes up quite high, I wanted to try to query the database and use a variable in the row name to return my value, except it keeps returning NULL values, probably because it isn't actually returning anything

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect(....);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
                echo $row->Row.$i;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I thought this would be the code but it doesnt work like this, currently I have the code set to

```
for(...
    $myrow = 'Row'.$i;
    echo $row->$myrow;
}
```

Which works although its a little sloppy and I assume there is a much nicer way of doing it

Comment: also maybe it should be "SELECT * FROM TableName" ?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a complete database structure fail. Having "a high number" of *columns* named *"RowN"* is terrible practice. Your structure needs serious normalization.

Comment: Well by 'high number' I mean less than 40, but this is because the rows for these fields will/could number in the thousands. I'm trying to mock up a fantasy football database (just between mates not a paid job) the 'RowN' would be each week and the row contains the players ID number so that I can eventually get a matrix with each players ID and their score week by week. @KasiaGogolek, The "SELECT.." string was just an example, the TableName was meant to be a column just like the Row1, Row2...

Comment: Still a structural fail, you need to normalize your database. Learn about how to model has-many/belongs-to and many-to-many relationships in relational databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you mean:

```
$row->{'Row'.$i};
```

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, though,

Comment: If this is what you meant, take note of @deceze 's comment above.

Comment: I feel bad for answering this now.