# Variable for the field name of mysql row result

Tags: php, mysql, variables, field

I'm retrieving a row with php from mysql and it has fields like: name_en, name_es, name_de...

I want to retrieve the right field base on my $lang variable (en, es, de...). If the $lang variable is 'es', I'd need to get $row['name_es'].

I've tried this (based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017047/php-variable-in-mysql-row-name)), but it's not working:

```
$name = $row->{'name_'.$lang};
```

Any idea how can I use a variable as the name of the field of a row?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have? `$row['name_es']`

try it:

```
$name = $row['name_'.$lang];
```

Comment: that worked! I don't know how I didn't try this before... thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have an object in `$row`

```
$field = 'name_' . $lang;
$name = $row->$field;
```